# Insert file in map

Tags: c++, file, dictionary

I'm new to c++.
I have two .txt file. one is 3 key words that I want to find in the other .txt file witch is a long texte. I'm trying to insert the two files in a map but I don't know how.

I have tried this 
`num.insert(pair<string,string>(clef,index));` 
but it dosen't work. please help me.

thanks in advance :)

@Ari0nhh this is all my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


ofstream index( "index.txt", ios::out | ios::app);


int main()
{
    map <string, string> num;
    map <string,string> ::iterator it;
    int ctrLigne = 1;
    int ctrPage=1;
    int ctr=1;


    ifstream docum ("docum.txt", ios::in);
    ifstream clef ("clef.txt", ios::in);

    /* what I have tried but did not work
        while (docum >> clef >> index){
            num[clef] = index;
        }



    num.insert(pair<string,string>(clef,index));
    num.insert(clef, index);
    */



    if (docum)
    {
        string ligne;

        while(getline(docum, ligne))
        {
            cout << ligne << " Ligne : " << ctrLigne << " Page : " << ctrPage << endl;

            if(ctr==4)
            {
                ctr=0;
                ctrPage++;
            }

            ctrLigne++;

            ctr++;
    }


    docum.close();
    clef.close();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You're going to need more context around "doesn't work"

Comment: Please post your entire code, essential to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a simple map and store the content of the file as a long string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string fileName="myFile.txt";
    string myFilecontent="All The secrets of the world\n Line 1\n Line2";//includes line breaks
    map<string,string> fileMap;
    fileMap[fileName]=myFilecontent;
    cout<<fileMap[fileName];
    return 0;
}
```

Ouput:

All The secrets of the world

Line 1

Line2

Hope that helps,